# How can I calculate similarity between two strings that have been rotated?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, some of which are completely different from the others, and some are variations of one another, that have been rotated x times. I would like to determine from the list which of those strings are equal, save for the rotation. I don't really know how to approach this task, but I have tried using `difflib.SequenceMatcher()` as well as `Levenstein.ratio()`. It may be that I can go with one of those and just take the set of strings resulting in the highest ratio, but I would like to know if there is a different or better way of approaching the problem.

For reference, here's an example of the list of strings:

`['1010', '122a916b2a916b7667110161', '20000000', '2020', '2a916b', '2a916b7667110161122a916b', '6b7667110161122a916b2a91', '916b7667110161122a916b2a', 'ffff']`

Each of the longer strings are composed of the same characters and can be rotated n times until they are equal to one another.

Comment: "I would like to determine from the list which of those strings are equal, save for the rotation"  So you want to check for equality, not similarity, right? the output should be a boolean as I understand.

Comment: What is your expected output? A list of groups?

Comment: Yes, a list of groups. From this list, only the following strings would be returned `'122a916b2a916b7667110161', '2a916b7667110161122a916b', '6b7667110161122a916b2a91', '916b7667110161122a916b2a'`, while the others would be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key trick would be the rotation check for two strings: `s1 in 2*s2`

```
data = ['1010', '122a916b2a916b7667110161', '20000000', '2020', '2a916b',
        '2a916b7667110161122a916b', '6b7667110161122a916b2a91', 
        '916b7667110161122a916b2a', 'ffff']

d = {}
for s in data:
    for k in d:
        if len(s) == len(k) and s in 2*k:
            d[k].append(s)
            break
    else:
        d[s] = [s]

[g for g in d.values() if len(g) > 1]
# [['122a916b2a916b7667110161', '2a916b7667110161122a916b', '6b7667110161122a916b2a91', '916b7667110161122a916b2a']]
```

If you have lots of data, you could presort/group the strings by length (and letter counts) and only check for rotations within the predetermined group.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the string:

```
abcdef
```

You can split it in half, to obtain the first part and the last part, lets call it prefix and suffix

```
prefix: abc 
suffix: def
```

Now if a string is rotated, no matter how many positions, there will still be either the prefix or suffix intact

```
bcdefa     suffix def intact
cdefab     suffix def intact
defabc     suffix def and prefix abc intact
efabcd     prefix abc intact
fabcde     prefix abc intact
```

So, basically you check if the prefix or suffix exist inside the rotated string.

- If both exist: Match
- If neither exist: No match.
- If one of them exist, from the position of the substring you know the rotation, you can then compare the rest with the prefix

Eg:

`cDEFab`  suffix found `def` in position 1

Comparing prefix to position 1+size of suffix(3) =4

```
cDEFab
    abc
```

Found ab. then the rest "c" you compare at the beginning of the string. and it matches.  Strings are equal

```
cDEFAB
c
```

Now you just need to implement it.

Comment: Or just: `len(s1) == len(s2) and s1 in 2*s2`